# How do I switch apps from the firebase cli?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

This seems like something which should be pretty easy to do, but for whatever reason, I'm being defeated.

I'm trying to use the firebase-tools CLI to interact with my database. I'm able to login without any trouble, and when I type `firebase list`, I get a list of all my current apps. It also tells me which app I'm currently connected to.

My problem is, I want to connect to one of the other apps. I'm running queries on my staging app, and I need to run them on my production app. I can see the production app in the list, but I'm not finding any way to switch to that app.

Thoughts?

Comment: if having issues listing projects use `firebase projects:list`

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Found some useful information here [Firebase CLI Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/).

The following code works for me.

```
firebase use <project_id>
```

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html - for a quick reference

Comment: If you're running on a CLI don't forget the `--token` otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 47):

I rather use scripts. Consider a project structure like this:

```
your-project
├── .firebaserc
└── functions
   ├── package.json
   └── index.js
```

Go to `.firebaserc` and follow the next example

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project-name",
    "prod": "other-name"
  }
}
```

Then go to `package.json` and add the following scripts (`changeToProd`, and `changeToDev`).

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "changeToProd": "firebase use prod",
    "changeToDev": "firebase use default"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

If your IDE support npm scripts you can run them using the IDE UI, otherwise it can be run using the command console. Make sure you are inside the `functions` folder.

```
npm run-script changeToProd
```

You can verify your current project by running the following command from the terminal or added to the scripts as we just did

```
firebase use
```

Comment: Welcome, my approach is intended to be sharable with the rest of the team :)

Comment: I tried this out, and it works. Using this method prevents me from making silly mistakes of interchanging the environment wrongly.

Answer (score 40):

If you are using Node.js on windows, your answer should be

```
firebase use <project_id>
```

but without the <> for example

```
firebase use chat-app-2a150
```

You can use the following code to view all your projects so as to pick the correct project ID to use

```
firebase projects:list
```

Comment: You may need to logout of the CLI and log back in to see reference a new project id

Answer (score 38):

**2020:**

The officially recommended way is to use "alias":

In your `.firebaserc`, set different project IDs like this:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "production": "my-project-id",
    "testing": "my-testing-project-id"
  }
}
// you can also add them interactively with `firebase use --add`
```

Then switch projects in CLI with `firebase use testing` , `firebase use production`.

Note: switching projects won't create any git diff, it's simply remembered in your local machine. Use `firebase use` to see which project is currently being used.

Uncommon cases:

- If you want to use your own ID without committing changes to the project owner's `.firebaserc`, do `firebase use my-own-id` locally as mentioned in the accepted answer.
- If you want people to fork your code then use their own IDs, add `.firebaserc` into `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 17):

In the directory where you run `firebase list`, there will be a file called `firebase.json`. If you open that in a text editor, you will see the app name in there. You can change it there or delete `firebase.json` to change the app.

Or save yourself the hassle of editing a text file and do as Jason says: use `firebase init`.

Comment: Is there a change now? Because I cannot find the app name in firebase.json but can find it in .firebaserc.... Appreciate the clarification...

Comment: The project name is indeed in `.firebaserc` now.

Comment: Might be wrong but this doesn't seem to switch the database. Deploying will deploy to "current" project but it seems to still pull data from original database. Pretty damn dangerous if you're going use this to separate production from staging environments. Hope no one loses their prod data. :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue that @Enric described about accessing the default database while being on a different project. Is there some way to detect what project is being used on the client side so that I can change the config to initialize the app appropriately?

Comment: make sure you change firebaseConfig ` // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "new-project.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https:/new-project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "new-project-id",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase`

Answer (score 8):

you can just use a command line switch

```
--project=my-firebase-project
```

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but it seems that the original question was about changing apps  within a given project, rather than simply changing projects.

This answer is about changing apps and site_IDs within a project.

In my case I have a project (CoolProject) with 2 web apps:

- an assessment form: `form`
- a main website: `website`

Both apps are in separate repos both locally and in GitHub.

Each app has its own specific site_ID:

- form: `coolproject-form[.web.app]`
- website: `coolproject-website[.web.app]`

I first setup the `form` app and deployed without any issue to `coolproject-form`. But when I created the `web` app (and associated `coolproject-website` site_ID) and tried to deploy it using `firebase deploy --only hosting` or `firebase deploy --only hosting:website` it incorrectly deployed it to `coolproject-form` overwriting the `form` app.

This is how I eventually solved the issue (based on this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets)):

1. Check that both apps and corresponding site_IDs are correctly setup:

```
firebase apps:list
```

```
firebase hosting:sites:list
```

2. Setup up the `website` deploy target for hosting (via `.firebaserc`)

```
firebase target:apply hosting website coolproject-website
```

3. Update `firebase.json` (for the `website` app):

```
...
"hosting": [{
    "target": "website",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }],
...
```

4. Deploy

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

With this the `website` app is now correctly deployed to `coolproject-website.web.app`.

Answer (score 1):

Addition @cutiko's answer

In `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
...
"prod": "echo \"Switch to Production environment\" && firebase use prod && npm run runtimeconfig",
"dev": "echo \"Switch to Development environment\" && firebase use default && npm run runtimeconfig"
...
```

`npm run runtimeconfig` to get custom config environment

In `.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default":"{project-dev-id}",
    "prod": "{project-prod-id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to change firebase app destination project you can type  "firebase use myProjectName" . i also used the above answeres "firebase list" to check what project i have
( work for me in firebase cli 7.4  with angular 7 app)