# How to switch between two firebase projects in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have two Firebase projects one for the development of another for production. How do I switch between them in the root branch with cloud functions? Since for example I'm developing a new function and I want to do deploy only on the firebase development project and check how it works before doing deploy in the firebase production project.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your `index.js` file from the `functions` directory of your existing project to your new project and then deploy it to Firebase?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases).  In particular, you'll want to learn about the `firebase use` command to create aliases for your projects and switch between them for deployment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, did not write an answer to this, yes I already read it there, also found the information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432458/how-do-i-switch-apps-from-the-firebase-cli/36432783#36432783

Comment: firebase use --add