# Change firebase project in react app in order to deploy app

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a react app which is ready to deploy using node.js and firebase deploy.

The app is connected to 2 different firebase projects as it needed data from both. Currently, it is deploying to the wrong project. I would like it to deploy to the other project.

When I run 'firebase init' it doesn't give me the option to change the project the app is using as I have already set that when I first started.

Is there a way to either change the project it is using or specify which project to deploy to when I run firebase deploy?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432458/how-do-i-switch-apps-from-the-firebase-cli).

Can change the project using this command:

```
firebase use <project_id>
```