# How to change the hosting domain being uploaded into?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

`firebase deploy --only hosting`

uploads to one of the 2 domains, how can i change to the other one I created?

is it done by the firebase dashboard or CLI?

**thanks**

`firebase deploy --only hosting`

deploys into name-12345.web.app instead into name.web.app which I created

**Possible related answer and solution** in [How do I switch apps from the firebase cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432458/how-do-i-switch-apps-from-the-firebase-cli?rq=2)

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you did to create this other domain.  You can't just "create" web.app subdomains - the names of those are automatically assigned by Firebase when you create your project with the same unique id of your project. Also you should know that the CLI can't choose which site alias is used for deployment.  All site aliases show the same data from the last deployment.

Comment: Yes you can create one if you go into project settings, new web app, and select there {this}.web.app when linking it to a storage. 

The thing I’m also having issues now, is when I deploy, is not loading what I see with npm start in react as preview in localhost. It’s like, uploading an older version of the site.

Comment: Please *edit the question* with more descriptive details on the steps you took to get to where you are now.  I'm unclear what you mean by "linking it to a storage". It would help immensely if you also provided screenshots if this is all in Firebase console, so we can see what you did.  If you are referring to any documentation, provide links to that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you create a project it gives you normally a name-ab12 that you can edit, some projects I’ve been able to select a different one. Then as it’s the main domain newname.web.app it deploys there, no problem. 

But, you can create more domains for your project, maybe when you select add new app, for example so you have 2 domains. How to change deploy to target second new domain inside same project?  Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432458/how-do-i-switch-apps-from-the-firebase-cli?rq=2